# how to get specific information from url html source code

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the information from a url links html source code onto another webpage which is in the same domain and get specific information from the html code, like getting the span id, and information from a `<td>`
and change the internal html code `<span id="myspan"> here is my text </span>`
to that of what I get.

the code I have below is not working, not sure why

```js
function loadHTML(spanId, url) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
                    handler(xmlhttp.responseText, spanId);
              }

    }

    }


    function handler(responseText, spanId) {
    var parser =new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(responseText, "text/html");

    //get class name from parser


    var status = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var className  = status[1].className;

    //get the date/time from parser 
    var tds = doc.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var dateTime = tds[0].innerText;


    var span = document.getElementById(spanId);
    span.id= className;
    span.innerHTML = dateTime;

    }

     loadHTML('myspan',"any given url");
```

```html
<span id="myspan"> here is my text </span>
```

Comment: Please explain what happens when you run your code. "Is not working" is not helpul in locating your problem.

Comment: I refresh the webpage and the text that is already there "here is my text " has not been modified.

Answer (score 0):

after xmlhttp.onreadystatechange you need to call xmlhttp.send() to start the http request

correct code is here

```js
function loadHTML(spanId, url) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
                    handler(xmlhttp.responseText, spanId);
              }

    }

    }

    // send() method actually initiates the ajax request
    xmlhttp.send();


    function handler(responseText, spanId) {
    var parser =new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(responseText, "text/html");

    //get class name from parser


    var status = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var className  = status[1].className;

    //get the date/time from parser 
    var tds = doc.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var dateTime = tds[0].innerText;


    var span = document.getElementById(spanId);
    span.id= className;
    span.innerHTML = dateTime;

    }

     loadHTML('myspan',"any given url");
```

```html
<span id="myspan"> here is my text </span>
```